# Objective C: incompatible pointer types sending

Tags: objective-c

I created a protocol, called `EventListener`:

```
@protocol EventListener
...
@end
```

I also have class, `Processor`, like:

```
// Processor.m
@synthesize listeners = _listeners; //@property NSMutableArray* in Processor.h

- (id) init {
   self = [super init];
   self.listeners = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //init with empty array
   return self;
}

- (void) addListener:(id<EventListener>)listener {
   [self.listeners addObject:listener];
}
```

I have another class, called `Plugin`:

```
@interface Plugin : NSObject <EventListener> { ... }
...
@end
```

and in its implementation, I perform:

```
// Plugin.m
[self.processor addListener:self];
```

and get warning that

> incompatible pointer types sending `Plugin*` sending to parameter of type `Listener*`

**What I've done wrong?**

---

I'm coming from java world and assume that because my Processor implements protocol it should be type of Listener, smith like:

```
interface Listener {
}

class Processor {
List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

   void addListener(Listener listener) {
      listeners.add(listener);
   }
}


class Plugin implements Listener {
   Processor processor = new Processor();

   void method() {
      processor.addListener(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is a Listener? I see EventListener in your code but there is no mention of Listener, so it is hard to see where the compiler's use of this term would come from.

Comment: Impossible to reproduce given faulty report of code and compiler error message. Voting to close on that basis.

Comment: @matt, in java example I have interface Listener defined, while in Objective-C it is called EventListener. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: No. You said that the compiler said `incompatible pointer types sending Plugin* sending to parameter of type Listener*`. I'm saying that given your code the compiler could not have said that, because it would never have heard of anything called Listener. You must copy and paste your _real_ code and show the _real_ compiler error if you want people to be able to reproduce the problem and help you. I implemented your code and got no error, so clearly you have not described things truthfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, classes and protocols are completely separate things and — unlike Java's classes and interfaces — have distinct syntax.

If you wanted to accept any class which is, or is a descendant of, the class `Listener` then the parameter would be:

```
Listener *
```

If you wanted to accept any class that implements the protocol `EventListener` then the parameter would be:

```
id <EventListener>
```

As `id` means "any class type" and the `<EventListener>` adds that whatever is passed should implement that protocol.

If you wanted to accept only those of `Listener` and its subclasses that implement `EventListener` then the parameter would be:

```
Listener <EventListener> *
```

That contrasts with Java where you'd take the interface type directly and not specify any class type constraints.

Comment: Yeah, that helped greatly, thanks. Problem was that I had
`- (void) addListener:(Listener*) listener
` in my header file instead of `- (void) addListener:(id<Listener>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same warning when you declared

```
@interface SomeClass <SomeProtocol> : NSObject
@end
```

instead of

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject<SomeProtocol>
@end
```

The first syntax is correct but it has no sense.